# moment-timezone:moment.tz(...).unix(...).format is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

I am trying to get date from a unix timestamp with a timezone using `moment-timzone`

```
var moment      = require('moment-timezone');

let date = moment.tz('Asia/Kolkata').unix(dateInUTC).format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s')
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
moment.tz(...).unix(...).format is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the npm packages **'moment'** and **'moment-timezone'** are installed, also whether the variable dateInUTC has the proper timestamp.

Then try

```
var momentTz      = require('moment-timezone');
let date = momentTz.unix(dateInUTC).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s');
```

Comment: two packages installed properly also i able to get the timestamp without  timezone

Comment: did you try this "moment.unix(dateInUTC).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-M-DD-H-mm-s')"  - having unix() first then tz()

Comment: also make sure that you have assigned require('moment-timezone') to an unique variable.